# $\int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} \frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy$ and $\int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} \frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am facing problem in calculating $$I_1=\int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} \frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \,dx\,dy$$ and $$I_2=\int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} \frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \,dy\,dx$$ after substituting $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ we have $I_1=\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} \int_{[0,1]}\frac{\cos(2\theta)}{r^2}r\,dr\, d\theta$ so I am getting $\infty \times 0=0$ So I am not getting $\pi/4$ and $-\pi/4$ resp.

Maybe there is a silly point I am missing. Please help.

Comment: How about just **doing** the integrals, as asked, and not "substituting"?

Comment: Yeah I am confused in not getting. May be a result of doing a lot of pure math :( .. sorry

Comment: Yeah I might get downvote but as I asked this question what I didn't get. So I am not going to erase the question. Thanks all of you for helping

Comment: Its a good question and you showed some effort.  Clearly a "trick" was needed.

Comment: The context is that this is a good example of how you have to be careful with switching integrals.

Comment: @RRL No trick is needed. The OP employed one though, in order to avoid doing the integrations.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: True.

Comment: @RRL I didn't want to avoid, by the way, rather say I forgot or couldn't that would be more respectful.

Comment: @Gimgim: The anti-derivatives don't exactly jump out at you so we can all move on.

Comment: In cases like this where the values of the two iterated integrals differ, so you have conditional convergence, two-variable substitutions involving Jacobian determinants are absolutely the wrong way to proceed.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\text{Let } & y = x\tan \theta, \\ {} \\
\text{so that }& dy = x\sec^2\theta\,d\theta \\ {} \\
\text{and } & x^2 + y^2= x^2\sec^2\theta,
\end{align}
and as $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$ then $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\arctan(1/x)$. Then$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: Then 
$$\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \, dy \\ {} \\
= {} & \int_0^{\arctan(1/x)} \frac{x^2 - x^2 \tan^2\theta}{(x^2 + x^2\tan^2\theta)^2} \big( x\sec^2\theta\,d\theta\big) \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 x \int_0^{\arctan(1/x)} \frac{1-\tan^2 \theta}{\sec^2 \theta} \, d\theta \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 x \int_0^{\arctan(1/x)} (\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta) \, d\theta \\ {} \\ = {} & \cdots \text{continued below} \end{align}$$

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
= {} & \frac 1 x \int_0^{\arctan(1/x)} \cos(2\theta) \, d\theta = \frac 1 {2x} \sin\left(2\arctan \frac 1 x\right) \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 x \sin\left(\arctan \frac 1 x \right) \cos\left( \arctan \frac 1 x \right) \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 x \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+x^2}} \cdot \frac x {\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac 1 {1+x^2}. \\ {} \\
\text{And then}
& \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac \pi 4.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Michael Hardy just copy paste it into an answer and i'll upvote :)

Comment: @BenjaminWang : I posted it as an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768872/how-to-solve-int-01dx-int-01-fracx2-y2x2y22-dy/3769021#3769021

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \left(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right)  $$

Comment: Thanks a lot....

Comment: You're welcome.  Perhaps you didn't need the second clue.

Comment: Yeah I might get downvote but as I asked this question what I didn't get. So I am not going to erase the question. Thanks all of you for helping