# How to solve $\int_0^1dx\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The original question is:

> Prove that:$$\begin{aligned}\\
> \int_0^1dx\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy\neq\int_0^1dy&\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\\
> \end{aligned}\\$$

But I can't evaluate the integral $$\int_0^1dx\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy$$
At first, I assumed $x^2+y^2=z^2$. But, it is so complicated. Then, I assumed $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. But, I can't calculate the limits. Solving the equations I got three values of $\theta$ i.e. $\theta=0$, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. I am just confused. Please help.

Comment: Forget $x$, and integrate $\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng if I break the integrals in two parts like $$\begin{aligned}\\\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}&-\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\\end{aligned}\\$$ then also i can't evaluate the second part.

Comment: Aren't they going to be equal and of the opposite sign? judging by the summery.

Comment: Since the point of this example is that the integrations don't commute, it's not a good idea to try a multivariate transformation in the spirit of $dxdy=rdrd\theta$.

Comment: I've posted an answer that gets this result via the most routine sorts of freshman-calculus methods.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3042343/321264

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_0^1\frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\, dy = \int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \left(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)\, dy =  \frac{1}{1+x^2} $$

Comment: I might add a second step along the lines of$$\cdots=\int_0^1\frac{(x^2+y^2)\cdot1-2y\cdot y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\mathrm{d}y$$to make the quotient rule more apparent.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thank you, for explaining this.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\text{Let } & y = x\tan \theta, \\[8pt]
\text{so that }& dy = x\sec^2\theta\,d\theta \\[8pt]
\text{and } & x^2 + y^2= x^2\sec^2\theta,
\end{align}
and as $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$ then $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\arctan(1/x)$.

Then
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \, dy \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^{\arctan(1/x)} \frac{x^2 - x^2 \tan^2\theta}{(x^2 + x^2\tan^2\theta)^2} \big( x\sec^2\theta\,d\theta\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 x \int_0^{\arctan(1/x)} \frac{1-\tan^2 \theta}{\sec^2 \theta} \, d\theta \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 x \int_0^{\arctan(1/x)} (\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta) \, d\theta \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 x \int_0^{\arctan(1/x)} \cos(2\theta) \, d\theta
= \frac 1 {2x} \sin\left(2\arctan \frac 1 x\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 x \sin\left(\arctan \frac 1 x \right) \cos\left( \arctan \frac 1 x \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 x \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+x^2}} \cdot \frac x {\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac 1 {1+x^2}. \\[5pt]
\text{And then}
& \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac \pi 4.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{align}\int\dfrac{x^2 - y^2}{\left(x^2 + y^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm dy&\equiv \int\dfrac{2x^2}{\left(x^2 + y^2\right)^2}  - \dfrac{x^2 + y^2}{\left(x^2 + y^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm dy\\ &= 2x^2\int\dfrac1{\left(x^2 + y^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm dy - \int\dfrac1{x^2 + y^2}\,\mathrm dy\end{align}$$

The first integral can be solved with the help of a [reduction formula](https://www.math24.net/reduction-formulas-integrals/). The second integral is straightforward to solve (substitute $t = \dfrac yx$ if you get stuck).

Comment: I was just finding an easy step for the first part, after seeing your answer.

Comment: . . . and as I said, "solve" is the wrong word here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy ... sure, we can replace the word with _evaluate_.